# Why do some figure spaces have darker outlines?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

On the figure collection screen for Volume 1, there are 7 figure spaces at the bottom that have darker grey outlines compared to the other figures.

Is there any significance to the figure spaces with darker outlines?

[image: figure collection vol 1]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means that those figures are not available from the gacha machine, but you have to make something specific in the game in order to get them. Selecting one of these spots will show you the unlock condition.

Also, they will have a golden crown in the lower-left corner when unlocked.

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that hovering over those spots before unlocking them will give a tooltip on how to get it.

Comment: Some of the dark outlined figures in volume 4 are added to the gacha machine after meeting the unlock conditions, rather than being given directly.